# snake result in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm trying to obtain a snake like outcome (left to right, top down) of a set of characters in Python 3.
I have managed to do so using zip, the following is some sample code:

```
>>> abcd = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> i = iter(abcd)
>>> t = zip(i,i)
>>> for x in t:
...   print(x)
... 
('a', 'b')
('c', 'd')
>>> for g in zip(abcd,abcd):
...   print(g)
... 
('a', 'a')
('b', 'b')
('c', 'c')
('d', 'd')
```

But I'd like to understand why zip(abcd,abcd) does not return the same result as zip(i,i) ?

Answer (score 0):

Zip make a tuples with two list and make a tuple (a,a) (b,b) (c,c) (d,d)

Iter() iterate through it using next() hence when You are using Iter() function it make tuple of (a,b) (c,d)

Comment: I assumed that zip takes a list of iterables, not iterators as parameters, at least that is my understanding from the definition, def zip(*iterables)